# How can i get data from my import.io API?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, import.io

Im trying to get data from my import.io APi, i want to display this data on my site in an unorderd list .

Can you tell how to do this?

This is what I have so far:

```js
document.addEventListener('deviceready', onDeviceReady, false);

function onDeviceReady() {
    //console.log('device is ready');
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: 'https://api.import.io/store/connector/93f9c80c-f8c1-4a5f-807c-f70f88630972/_query?input=webpage/url:http%3A%2F%2Fnuzzel.com%2FWAStatzz&&_apikey=e4fb993c758a43dda0ca9135d3b3264deebed4b302b0d342e2b3fabb2b49afc9c14493d0d53d65d0ea2a0fd19b45f6d10cda5252f76410921188d38cb4e6db8fc28527d64207329b2c86bdc5119bac97',
        dataType: 'json',
        crossDomain: true,
        success: function(data) {
            console.log(data); //The log dont show me nothing.
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's seems that your API works perfectly.

Here is an example of how to show a list with all `headline`'s for each item.

I just replaced `deviceready` with `DOMContentLoaded` to make it works on desktop.

```js
//document.addEventListener('deviceready', onDeviceReady, false);
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', onDeviceReady, false);
function onDeviceReady() {
  //console.log('device is ready');
  $.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: 'https://api.import.io/store/connector/93f9c80c-f8c1-4a5f-807c-f70f88630972/_query?input=webpage/url:http%3A%2F%2Fnuzzel.com%2FWAStatzz&&_apikey=e4fb993c758a43dda0ca9135d3b3264deebed4b302b0d342e2b3fabb2b49afc9c14493d0d53d65d0ea2a0fd19b45f6d10cda5252f76410921188d38cb4e6db8fc28527d64207329b2c86bdc5119bac97',
    dataType: 'json',
    crossDomain: true,
    success: function(data) {
      var result = data.results;
      var list = $('ul');
      for (var i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
          list.append('<li><b>headline</b>:' + result[i].headline + '</li>');
      }
    }
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul id="result">
  
</ul>
```